# POD structs containing constant member

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, c++03

With this code:

```
struct A
{
    int i;
    const int b;
};

// The union is to verify that A is a type that can be used in a union.
union U
{
    A a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    U a = {1, 1};
    U b = {2, 1};
}
```

g++ version 4.8.3 complains about an error:

```
a.cpp:9:4: error: member ‘A U::a’ with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
  A a;
    ^
a.cpp:9:4: note: unrestricted unions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

but clang 3.5.0 compiles this code without error. Which one is correct? Is this a compiler bug?

**My attempt at solving this:**

From the C++03 standard section 9.5 paragraph 1:

> In a union, at most one of the data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the data members can be stored in a union at any time. [Note: one special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a POD-union contains several POD-structs that share a common initial sequence (9.2), and if an object of this POD-union type contains one of the POD-structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of POD-struct members; see 9.2. ] The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its data members. Each data member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a struct. A union can have member functions (including constructors and destructors), but not virtual (10.3) functions. A union shall not have base classes. A union shall not be used as a base class. **An object of a class with a non-trivial constructor (12.1), a non-trivial copy constructor (12.8), a non-trivial destructor (12.4), or a non-trivial copy assignment operator (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a member of a union, nor can an array of such objects**. If a union contains a static data member, or a member of reference type, the program is ill-formed.

From the C++03 standard section 12.8 paragraphs 10 and 11:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. The implicitly-declared copy assignment operator for a class X will have the form `X& X::operator=(const X&)` if each direct base class B of X has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type const B&, const volatile B& or B, and for all the nonstatic data members of X that are of a class type M (or array thereof), each such class type has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type const M&, const volatile M& or M.
>
> `Otherwise, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator will have the form X& X::operator=(X&)`
>   ...
>
> **A copy assignment operator for class X is trivial if it is implicitly declared and if class X has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and each direct base class of X has a trivial copy assignment operator, and for all the nonstatic data members of X that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class type has a trivial copy assignment operator**; otherwise the copy assignment operator is non-trivial.

I'm not sure which compiler is correct because I don't know if a constant member has a trivial copy assignment operator.

**Edit:**
The compilation commands are:

```
clang++ a.cpp -o a
g++ a.cpp -o a
```

**Edit2:**
To show that g++ isn't complaining about A::b being `const` but A doesn't have a constructor, I also tried this program:

```
struct A
{
    int i;
    const int b;
};

int main()
{
    A a = {1, 1};
}
```

This compiled without errors on both g++ and clang++:

```
g++ b.cpp -o b
clang++ b.cpp -o b
```

Comment: Does clang 3.5 default to C++11?

Comment: clang does not default to C++11. But I tested it with -std=c++03 and it still does not produce an error.

Comment: Beautiful testcase ... except we're missing build commands!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As correctly noted by you the copy assignment operator is implicitly **declared** and trivial. 
Same goes for the default constructor, which is also trivial and implicitly declared.

Note though that both of these member functions aren't implicitly **defined** - that only happens when they are used, [class.ctor]/7:

> An implicitly-declared default constructor for a class is *implicitly
>   defined* when it is used to create an object of its class type (1.8).

.. which is clearly not the case here.
That's the key difference, and the reason that @dasblinkenlight's quote is irrelevant for this matter: The default constructor is never defined, thus the paragraph on missing *mem-initializer-id*s doesn't apply.

How are `const` members and the assignment operator connected then? Here:

> An implicitly-declared copy assignment operator is *implicitly defined* **when an object of its class type is assigned a value of its class type or a value of a class type derived from its class type.**
>    A program is ill-formed if the class for which a copy assignment
>   operator is implicitly **defined** has:
>
> - **a nonstatic data member of `const` type**, or [..]

Thus the program would be ill-formed if the copy assignment operator would be used. But it isn't. All the special member functions are solely declared, and any restrictions on the `const`-ness of non-static data members only apply on implicitly defined special member functions.

As an example, take

```
struct A
{
    int i;
    const int b;
};

int main()
{
    A a = {1, 1};
}
```

Which [compiles fine under GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51e646785c251020). Your program should be well-formed, too, as all requirements on trivialty of special member functions of union members are met by `A`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Removed that part, didn't like it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1. Just to clarify, you think that this is a G++ compiler bug?

Comment: @qbt937 Certainly. I'll check the SVN repo version and then submit a bug report.

Comment: I have tested it in 4.9.2, and it still fails with the same error. I just found a bug reported for g++ 4.3.1 that I think is the same: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39934

Comment: ,@Columbo Could you add a link to this Stackoverflow question in either the link to bug two comments above, or to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64428 which I assume you posted and has been resolved as invalid. There seems to be some debate about whether it is a compiler bug -- at least in bug #39934. Unfortunately I don't have a GCC Bugzilla account and GCC Bugzilla account creation has been restricted.

Comment: @qbt937 That was solely a typo though. After Jonathan simply marked it invalid I couldn't be bothered to create a second one.

Comment: @qbt937 I suppose it suffices to create a new bug report that doesn't contain a typo :P