# Union containing volatile structs

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, volatile, unions, c++03

This seems to be similar to [POD structs containing constant member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665567/pod-structs-containing-constant-member), but sort of reversed.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
};

union U
{
    volatile A a;
    long b;
};

int main()
{
    U u1;
    U u2;

    u1.a.a = 12;
    u2 = u1;
    std::cout << u2.a.a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

g++ 4.8.3 compiles this code without error and it runs correctly:

```
$ g++ -std=c++03 a.cpp -o a_gcc
$ ./a_gcc
12
```

But clang++ 3.5.1 produces an error (I have manually wrapped the error message to keep the code box from scrolling):

```
$ clang++ -std=c++03 a.cpp -o a_clang
a.cpp:8:7: error: member function 'operator=' not viable: 'this'
argument has type 'volatile A', but function is not marked volatile
union U
      ^
a.cpp:3:8: note: 'operator=' declared here
struct A
       ^
a.cpp:20:5: note: implicit copy assignment operator for 'U' first
required here
        u2 = u1;
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Does C++03 allow the program to copy-assign a union containing volatile structs? I could not find anything in the C++03 standard that defines the default copy constructor of a union.

I would like to know which compiler is correct or if the standard isn't clear on that point.

**Edit:** I found out that if I use copy construction instead of copy assignment that both clang++ and g++ will compile the program without error. Specifically if I change `main` to be:

```
int main()
{
    U u1;

    u1.a.a = 12;
    U u2 = u1;
    std::cout << u2.a.a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

.. then it will work. I wonder why they are treated differently by clang++.

Comment: What if you add a user-defined assignment operator in `union U`: `volatile U& operator =(const volatile U&) volatile`?  Or perhaps with only some of those `volatile`s?

Comment: Why not make instances of the union volatile instead of having the union's members be volatile? It seems easier to reason about its behavior that way.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Because then it won't cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, the union's copy constructor can be deleted. We see this from a note in [class.union], §9.5 in N4140:

> *[Note:* If any non-static data member
>   of a union has a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8),
>   copy assignment operator (12.8), move assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding
>   member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union. *—end note ]*

And in [class.copy], §12.8/25, we see that our `union` has a non-trivial copy constructor:

> A copy/move assignment operator for class X is trivial if it is not user-provided, its parameter-type-list is
>   equivalent to the parameter-type-list of an implicit declaration, and if ...
>   — [ .. ]
>   — class X has **no non-static data members of volatile-qualified type**, and

But that particular line in [class.copy] was only added a result of [Is a volatile-qualified type really a POD?](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#496) Before then, such a class would still be considered to have a trivial copy constructor.

So it's my understanding that in C++03, there is no indication that the union's copy constructor should be deleted, and in C++11, there is some indication of this but it is non-normative.

Comment: Note that the rule you quoted does not actually apply, since it is the union itself whose copy-assignment operator is non-trivial, but the rule talks about the operators for members... and the copy assignment operator for `class A` *is* trivial.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hm. Then I got nothing.

Comment: I think this is still valuable, but definitely non-normative.

Comment: @Barry Interesting reference to C++11. If I compile my test program in C++11 mode both g++ and clang++ will error that the copy assignment operator of U is implicitly deleted.

Comment: @Barry For C++11 I think the relevant quote is "a non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s corresponding assignment operator, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted assignment operator, or ..." from 12.8/24. The default copy assignment operator of the member can't be used because the default copy assignment operator can't handle volatile (see 12.8/19 and it's footnote). But that is only for C++11, and I haven't been able to find anything for C++03

Comment: Sorry to down vote, but this does not answer the question (because it is about C++03), and I would like to keep this in the unanswered questions list until I get an answer. I will undownvote your answer if/when I get an answer which answers the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing more than a bug in that particular version of GCC.

C++03 [class.copy]/10 governs the signature of the implicitly declared copy assignment operator for a class. For a class named `X`, it is either `X& operator=(const X&)` (most common) or `X& operator=(X&)` (less common). In the case of `A`, the copy assignment operator's signature is `A& operator=(const A&)`. Note that this means that you cannot call this assignment operator with a volatile or const volatile value of type `A`.

Similarly, the implicitly declared assignment operator for `U` will have the signature `U& operator=(const U&)`. [class.copy]/13 explains how this implicitly declared assignment operator works:

> The implicitly-defined copy assignment operator for class `X` performs memberwise assignment of its subobjects. The direct base classes of `X` are assigned first, in the order of their declaration in the *base-specifier-
> list*, and then the immediate nonstatic data members of `X` are assigned, in the order in which they were declared in the class definition. Each subobject is assigned in the manner appropriate to its type:
>
> - if the subobject is of class type, the copy assignment operator for the class is used (as if by explicit qualification; that is, ignoring any possible virtual overriding functions in more derived classes);
> - if the subobject is an array, each element is assigned, in the manner appropriate to the element type;
> - if the subobject is of scalar type, the built-in assignment operator is used.
>
> It is unspecified whether subobjects representing virtual base classes are assigned more than once by the
> implicitly-defined copy assignment operator. [...]

Thus, `U::operator=` behaves as though it were implemented like so:

```
U& operator=(const U& other) {
    a = other.a;
    b = other.b;
    return *this;
}
```

And `a = other.a` is ill-formed, because `other.a` has type `volatile A`, and `A` doesn't have an assignment operator that can accept `volatile A`.

That particular version of GCC probably accepted it because it converted the assignment into a trivial copy operation (*i.e.* as if by `memcpy`). It is allowed to do that, but only if the semantic requirements for the assignment are met in the first place. It is not allowed to fail to diagnose a diagnosable error because it decided to perform a particular optimization.

[over.match.oper]/1 makes it clear that if at least one operand for an operator has class type, then overload resolution must be done. In an assignment expression of the form

```
a = other.a
```

both operands have class type. [over.match.oper]/3 then explains that the candidates consist of the member candidates, non-member candidates, and built-in candidates. Non-member `operator=` is permitted, so the second set is empty. The member candidate is `A::operator=(const A&);`. The list of possible built-in candidates is given in [over.built], but there is no built-in candidate whose left argument is a reference to class type, and [over.match.oper]/4 forbids attempting to perform a user-defined conversion on the left argument in order to convert it to something that a built-in `operator=` candidate can accept. So the overload resolution rules preclude any possibility that assigning to an `A` object can be interpreted as a use of a built-in operator. It always must call an assignment operator function, and as I explained previously, the assignment operator for `A` cannot accept a volatile argument. The compiler must diagnose this.